# How to find corners in ArcGis maps?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, arcgis

I have an ArcGis map ploted in a browser and a lot of graphic pins printed above it. Those pins should be loaded lazily for performance purposes.

So I imagine if I could calculate the Lat and Lon of my corners I could simply make a query to bring me the pins inside the range.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using ArcGis Javascript API? If so, you can use the FeatureLayer with ONDEMAND mode to get the functionality you have described.

If you dont have the "pins" as a service, I would suggest you to setup a FeatureService. otherwise, take a look at the FeatureCollection object.